# Joining models to get records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Is there a better way to refactor the join and fetch the required attributes or is there any better option here?

```
 #student.rb 
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :subjects
end

 #subject.rb 
Class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student

  def self.get_all_subjects_and_student_info
    protocol_sponsor_joined
  end

  def self.get_one_subject_and_student_info(subject_id)
    subject_student_joined.where(id: subject_id).first 
  end
  # Description: This method will perform a basic join & return the required
  #results to its calling functions.
  def self.subject_student_joined
    @result ||= Subject.select('subjects.*, students.name AS STUDENT_NAME').joins(:student)
  end

end

 #subjects_controller.rb 
Class SubjectsController < ApplicationController 
  def show  
   #GET a subject and it's associated STUDENT_NAME
   @subject = Subject.get_one_subject_and_student_info(params[:id])
  end

  def index
   # get all subjects info(along with the subjects STUDENT_NAME)
   @subjects = Subject.get_all_subjects_and_student_info
  end
end
```

Comment: I always think, that joins are the best